# unicode not displaying from bat

Tags: windows, batch-file, unicode, cmd

my unicode characters aren't displaying correctly from a run batch file but they display fine in the cmd prompt

(note: you have to have set cmd to use consolas for this to work)

so i have a text file that contains

```
╔══════╗
║      ║
╚══════╝
```

and a bat file that contains

```
chcp 65001
@echo off 
cls
type textfile.txt
pause
```

when i open a cmd window and type in `chcp 65001` then `type textfile.txt` i get

```
﻿╔══════╗
║      ║
╚══════╝
```

but if i try to run the bat file all i get is

```
´╗┐ÔòöÔòÉÔòÉÔòÉÔòÉÔòÉÔòÉÔòù
Ôòæ      Ôòæ
ÔòÜÔòÉÔòÉÔòÉÔòÉÔòÉÔòÉÔòØ
```

which is what normally happens if i dont use chcp.. for some reason when run from a bat file the type command isn't using the type page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It happens because your batch file is saved in UTF8 encoding with a standard 3-byte BOM (Byte Order Mark) at the beginning. These characters aren't recognized by CMD interpreter, it sees them as a part of the first line and naturally can't execute `???chcp`.

- Resave your file in UTF-8 without BOM
- Or add an empty line at the beginning

Comment: I didn't know what BOM was and I saved the file in notepad (which doesn't give an option for BOM) while i was trying to get the symbols to work from the bat file so thanks!